# java how to get value quickly from a map with one entry

Tags: java

java get value from map with one entry:

```
Map<String, Object> map = ....
```

the map has one entry, but do not know its key. To get its value:

```
Object value = map.values().iterator().next();
```

Is there a quick way?

Comment: Yes.  You found it.  That's as good as it gets.

Comment: If the `Map` is a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), e.g. a `TreeMap`, you can call `map.firstEntry().getValue()`.